# How do objects get disconnected to its clients?

Tags: excel, vba

I made the code below from Excel 2016 VBA.

```
Private Sub useridno_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim ret_type As Integer
    Dim strTitle As String

    strTitle = "Wrong User ID Number!"
    strMsg = " Would you like to try again?"

    If Me.useridno.Value <> 1 Then
        ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, strTitle)

        Select Case ret_type
            Case 6
                Me.useridno.SetFocus
                Me.useridno.Text = ""
            Case 7
                Unload Me
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

When I run it, it returns the following error:

[image: Disconnected to its clients!]

This happens when I choose the "No" button in the message box. Why is this so?

Comment: change the datatype to variant  Dim ret_type As Integer to Dim ret_type As Variant

Comment: What sort of control is `useridno` ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, that is a textbox in my userform.

Comment: @Sixthsense, im still getting the same problem. :(

Comment: Instead of Unload Me use me.hide.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your project you have a `Show` command which displays the userform. From that moment forward the userform is in control. The code following the `Show` command will resume when the userform is closed. The command to do so is `Me.Hide` as @Storax has pointed out.

Your code has `Unload Me` instead. The error occurs when the other procedure tries to refer to the userform after the `Show` command. Your code might try to read some of the data from the form or there might be an innocuous `Set UserForm = Nothing`. It is already unloaded and can't, therefore, be referred to anymore.

The correct way would be to unload the form in the calling procedure, following the `Show` command and after you have retrieved all data from the form that you might want to use. Then, if you wish to explicitly release the form's object variable from memory you can do so.

Comment: Noted sir. Thank you. I got it now! :) Thank also to Storax!